# How can I get string from the blob (an id) stored in fusionauth DB?

Tags: java, fusionauth

For analytical purposes I want to run query against Fusionauth DB. But the id fields are stored as binary blobs. Do you have a function (java or sql) I can use to convert this blob into a string?

Comment: Once you converted blob to byte array, you can simply call `new String(byteArray)` to create a string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using MySQL. FusionAuth uses UUIDs for unique Ids, and in MySQL we store these as `BINARY(16)`.

If you want to select this value in a human readable form, you can perform a select such as `SELECT HEX(id) FROM table_name`.

If you want to select this column and deserialize it into a Java UUID type, you can use code similar to the following:

```java
public UUID fromByteArray(byte[] ba) {
  long msb = 0;
  long lsb = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    msb = (msb << 8) | (ba[i] & 0xff);
  }
  for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++) {
    lsb = (lsb << 8) | (ba[i] & 0xff);
  }
  return new UUID(msb, lsb);
}
```